# Create-react-app: what is the server (of npm start script)?

Tags: create-react-app

I want to understand what is the server created by the npm start command.
Is it like a nodejs server or something like that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It starts nodejs server. As given in the docs:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html